# How to reproduce the convex body from the Minkowski functional of it?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-explanation, convex-analysis

The following is from Bruckner's Real Analysis book (Just after Theorem 12.41) :

[image]

How to prove $S = {\{ x: p_S(x) \le 1}\}$? Here p is a nonnegative, positively homogeneous, subadditive functional on a linear space X.

Comment: In general $p_S(\cdot)$, the Minkowski functional  associated to $S$, only satisfies
$\{x:p_S(x)<1\}\subset S\subset\{x:p_S(x)\leqslant 1\}$.
$\Rightarrow\:$ May it be that we lack some information here, i. e., that the question is incomplete?

Answer (score 0):

Let $S \subseteq X$ be a convex body with $0$ as an interior point. Let us define $p_S(x) = \inf \{ r>0 : r^{-1}x \in S \}$.

Let us first prove that
$$ \{ x \in X : p_S(x) <1 \} \subseteq  S \subseteq \{ x \in X : p_S(x) \leq 1 \}$$

**Proof**:

1. If $x\in X$ and $p_S(x) <1$, then there is $r$, $0< r <1$ such that $r^{-1}x \in S$.  Since $S$ is convex and $0, r^{-1}x \in S$ and
   $ x= r (r^{-1}x)  + (1-r)0$ , we have that $x \in S$.  So, $ \{ x \in X : p_S(x) <1 \} \subseteq  S $.
2. If $x\in S$ then $ 1 \in \{r>0 : r^{-1}x \in S \}$. So $p_S(x) = \inf \{ r>0 : r^{-1}x \in S \} \leq 1$. So $S \subseteq \{ x \in X : p_S(x) \leq 1 \}$. $\square$.

Can we do better than that? Without additional assumptions, NO.

**Counter-example**:

Consider $X = \Bbb R^2$ with the euclidean norm, that is, for each $x=(x_1,x_2) \in X$, $\|x \|= \sqrt{x_1^2 +x_2^2}$

Let $B_0(1) = \{ x \in X : \|x\| < 1 \}$ and $B_0[1] = \{ x \in X : \|x\| \leq 1 \}$. Let $S \subseteq X$ such that $B_0(1) \subsetneq S \subsetneq B_0[1]$.

It is easy to prove that $S$ is a convex body having $0$ as an interior point. It is also easy to prove that, for all $x \in X$,  $p_S(x) = \|x\|$. So, we have
$$ \{ x \in X : p_S(x) <1 \}= B_0(1) \subsetneq  S \subsetneq B_0[1]=\{ x \in X : p_S(x) \leq 1 \}$$

Comment: This question was a story, LOL. I posted this question some days ago, and then immediately deleted it because I thought I understood it, then after three days I thought I was wrong then undeleted again then accepted a wrong answer and un-did the acceptance ... Overthinking and focus are not same and sometimes I really confuse them ... Anyways, I am clear with the solution now! Thanks a lot, indeed :)

Comment: Ramiro, you wrote "It is easy to prove that $S$ is a convex body having..." No, it is not because *$S$ need not be convex in general*. A possible counterexample lives in $\mathbb R^2$, equipped with the maximum norm $\left\|\binom x y\right\|_\infty = \max\{ |x|,|y|\}\,$.

Then  $B_0(1) =\left\{\binom x y : -1<x,y<1 \right\}$  and
$B_0[1]=\left\{\binom x y : -1\leqslant x,y\leqslant 1 \right\}$.

$S = B_0[1]\backslash \{\binom 01\}$ is not convex, but
$\,p_S(\cdot) = \|\cdot\|_\infty\,$.

Comment: @Hanno , In the counter-exemple I am using the euclidian norm. I wil make it explicit. Thanks for rising the point.

Answer (score 0):

As set $A$ in a topological linear space $X$ is called absorbent if for any $x\in X$, there is $t>0$ such that $t^{-1}x\in A$. For example, any open set that contains $0$ is absorbent by continuity of scalar product.

The following  is a well known result in convex analysis:

> Suppose that $A$ is convex and absorbent. Let $B=\{x\in X: \mu_A(x)<1\}$ and $C=\{x\in X:\mu_A(x)\leq 1\}$. Then, $B\subset A\subset C$ and $\mu_B=\mu_A=\mu_C$, where $$\mu_A(x)=\inf\{t>0: t^{-1}x\in A\}$$

The arguments is more or less as follows:

Since $A$ is convex and absorbent, $s>\mu_A(x)$ implies that
$s^{-1}x\in A$. Thus, if $\mu_A(x)<1$, then $x=1\,x\in A$, that is,
$B\subset A$. It is obvious that $A\subset C$.
It is easy to see that  $B$ and $C$ are convex. Since $\mu_A(\frac{1}{\mu_A(x)+1} x)<1$,   $B$ and $C$ are  absorbent. By definition of the Minkowski functional,  $\mu_C\leq \mu_A\leq \mu_B$.
For $x\in X$ fixed, consider $\mu_C(x)<s<t$. Then $s^{-1}x\in C$ and $\mu_A(t^{-1}x)=\frac{s}{t}\mu_A(s^{-1}x)<1$; hence  $\mu_B(x)<t$. By letting $t\searrow\mu_C(x)$,  we obtain that
$\mu_B(x)\leq \mu_c(x)$.

---

See if you can come up with counterexamples of equality (of sets) among the sets $A$, $B$ and $C$ in the statement I presented above.

Comment: Your second sentence is incorrect: The set $\{0\}$ is not absorbent. Another example is: a $1$-dimensional subspace in a higher-dimensional vector space is not absorbent.

Comment: @Hanno: there was a typo, I meant to write "any open" not "any one"

Comment: Thus a really semantic typo $\:\ddot\smile$